# Provide a Time-window for Users with ASP.NET Forms Auth

Tags: .net, asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm writing an ASP.NET web application that will be using forms auth. I would like users to have a login that is valid only from a given start date to a given end date. It's easy enough to flip the `IsApproved` flag to turn the login on or off, but that requires an outside source to determine when to do so.

The question: is there a simple method that I'm missing that's already built into the system, or will enabling such a time-window require at least some customization on my part (either by writing a custom provider, or writing a helper app that tracks the necessary data)?

I'm fine with the customization work if necessary, but I'd like to ensure that I don't do it if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
slidingExpiration="false"
```

on the  tag in the web.config.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration.aspx

also covered here: http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-cs  (Scroll to the **Specifying the Ticket's Timeout Value** section.)

and a caveat here: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/07/15/Forms-Authentication-Timeout.aspx